# H2OAutoML throws libgomp exception in train step

Tags: python, h2o

I run H2O on a docker image using Python 3.6.3 and H2O 3.26.0.3.

```
import h2o
from h2o.automl import H2OAutoML
h2o.init()
```

In this step, initialization is successful and it prints the following information.

```
H2O cluster uptime: 01 secs
H2O cluster timezone:   Europe/Istanbul
H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
H2O cluster version:    3.26.0.3
H2O cluster version age:    9 days
H2O cluster name:   H2O_from_python_96273_8m5wyj
H2O cluster total nodes:    1
H2O cluster free memory:    26.67 Gb
H2O cluster total cores:    72
H2O cluster allowed cores:  72
H2O cluster status: accepting new members, healthy
H2O connection url: http://127.0.0.1:54321
H2O connection proxy:   None
H2O internal security:  False
H2O API Extensions: Amazon S3, XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
Python version: 3.6.3 final
```

Now, I will run AutoML but it is problematic.

```
hf = h2o.H2OFrame(x_train)
aml = H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs=600)
aml.train(x = list(df.columns[:-1]), y = df.columns[-1], training_frame = hf)
```

I have the following error

> ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last) ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py
>   in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect,
>   assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked,
>   body_pos, **response_kw)
>       599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
>   --> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
>       601
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in
>   _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
>       383                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
>   --> 384                     six.raise_from(e, None)
>       385         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in
>   raise_from(value, from_value)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in
>   _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
>       379                 try:
>   --> 380                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
>       381                 except Exception as e:
>
> /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py in
>   getresponse(self)    1330             try:
>   -> 1331                 response.begin()    1332             except ConnectionError:
>
> /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py in
>   begin(self)
>       296         while True:
>   --> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
>       298             if status != CONTINUE:
>
> /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py in
>   _read_status(self)
>       257     def _read_status(self):
>   --> 258         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
>       259         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:
>
> /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py in
>   readinto(self, b)
>       585             try:
>   --> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
>       587             except timeout:
>
> ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last) ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in
>   send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
>       448                     retries=self.max_retries,
>   --> 449                     timeout=timeout
>       450                 )
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in
>   urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect,
>   assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked,
>   body_pos, **response_kw)
>       637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
>   --> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
>       639             retries.sleep()
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in
>   increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
>       367             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
>   --> 368                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
>       369             elif read is not None:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in
>   reraise(tp, value, tb)
>       684         if value.**traceback** is not tb:
>   --> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>       686         raise value
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in
>   urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect,
>   assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked,
>   body_pos, **response_kw)
>       599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
>   --> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
>       601
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in
>   _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
>       383                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
>   --> 384                     six.raise_from(e, None)
>       385         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in
>   raise_from(value, from_value)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in
>   _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
>       379                 try:
>   --> 380                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
>       381                 except Exception as e:
>
> /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py in
>   getresponse(self)    1330             try:
>   -> 1331                 response.begin()    1332             except ConnectionError:
>
> /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py in
>   begin(self)
>       296         while True:
>   --> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
>       298             if status != CONTINUE:
>
> /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py in
>   _read_status(self)
>       257     def _read_status(self):
>   --> 258         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
>       259         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:
>
> /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py in
>   readinto(self, b)
>       585             try:
>   --> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
>       587             except timeout:
>
> ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104,
>   'Connection reset by peer'))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call
>   last) ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py
>   in request(self, endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
>       404                                     headers=headers, timeout=self._timeout, stream=stream,
>   --> 405                                     auth=self._auth, verify=self._verify_ssl_cert, proxies=self._proxies)
>       406             self._log_end_transaction(start_time, resp)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in
>   request(method, url, **kwargs)
>        59     with sessions.Session() as session:
>   ---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>        61
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in
>   request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files,
>   auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert,
>   json)
>       532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
>   --> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>       534
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in
>   send(self, request, **kwargs)
>       645         # Send the request
>   --> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>       647
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in
>   send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
>       497         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
>   --> 498             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
>       499
>
> ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104,
>   'Connection reset by peer'))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> H2OConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 aml.train(x = list(df.columns[:-1]), y = df.columns[-1], training_frame = hf)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/automl/autoh2o.py in
>   train(self, x, y, training_frame, fold_column, weights_column,
>   validation_frame, leaderboard_frame, blending_frame)
>       443         poll_updates = ft.partial(self._poll_training_updates, verbosity=self._verbosity, state={})
>       444         try:
>   --> 445             self._job.poll(poll_updates=poll_updates)
>       446         finally:
>       447             poll_updates(self._job, 1)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/job.py in poll(self,
>   poll_updates)
>        55             pb = ProgressBar(title=self._job_type + " progress", hidden=hidden)
>        56             if poll_updates:
>   ---> 57                 pb.execute(self._refresh_job_status, print_verbose_info=ft.partial(poll_updates, self))
>        58             else:
>        59                 pb.execute(self._refresh_job_status)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/utils/progressbar.py in
>   execute(self, progress_fn, print_verbose_info)
>       169                 # Query the progress level, but only if it's time already
>       170                 if self._next_poll_time <= now:
>   --> 171                     res = progress_fn()  # may raise StopIteration
>       172                     assert_is_type(res, (numeric, numeric), numeric)
>       173                     if not isinstance(res, tuple):
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/job.py in
>   _refresh_job_status(self)
>        92     def _refresh_job_status(self):
>        93         if self._poll_count <= 0: raise StopIteration("")
>   ---> 94         jobs = h2o.api("GET /3/Jobs/%s" % self.job_key)
>        95         self.job = jobs["jobs"][0] if "jobs" in jobs else jobs["job"][0]
>        96         self.status = self.job["status"]
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py in api(endpoint, data,
>   json, filename, save_to)
>       102     # type checks are performed in H2OConnection class
>       103     _check_connection()
>   --> 104     return h2oconn.request(endpoint, data=data, json=json, filename=filename, save_to=save_to)
>       105 
>       106
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py in
>   request(self, endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
>       413             else:
>       414                 self._log_end_exception(e)
>   --> 415                 raise H2OConnectionError("Unexpected HTTP error: %s" % e)
>       416         except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
>       417             self._log_end_exception(e)
>
> H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: ('Connection aborted.',
>   ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

I suspect that proxy might be the reason of this exception. When I add the proxy information to the path, then exception message would be "HTTP 500 INKApi Error"

```
import os
os.environ['http_proxy']= ...
os.environ['https_proxy']= ...
```

JVM stdout log file dumps the following exception.

> [thread 140335217821440 also had an error][thread 140335320467200 also
>   had an error] [thread 140335207294720 also had an error]
>
> [thread 140335316256512 also had an error]# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> [thread 140335202031360 also had an error]
>     SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fa3276cdb8d, pid=51986, tid=0x00007fa2575f5700
>
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b04) (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
>    Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Problematic frame:
>    [thread 140335231506176 also had an error] C  [libc.so.6+0x39b8d][thread 140335341520640 also had an error]

JVM stderr log file contains interesting logs

> libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   *** Error in `/usr/bin/java': free(): corrupted unsorted chunks: 0x00007efe342f0240 ***
>
> libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable

Funny but It runs successfully when I run same code on my local machine. I suspect that it might be because of docker configuration.

Comment: Docker containers have a very small default memory, so we see issues caused by this all the time.  Make sure you give your Docker container a decent amount of memory and then give the H2O cluster a bit less memory than that.

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours on this problem but I can resolve it immediately when I post this question. It would be a typical **rubber duck programming**.

It seems that the engine consumes all resources of the server and exceeded its limits. This is the reason of "Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable" message.

Limiting memory and number of threads solves this problem.

```
h2o.init(ip="127.0.0.1",max_mem_size_GB = 40, nthreads = 2)
```

Comment: In your original post, you have 26.67GB in memory given to the H2O cluster and here you are actually using *more* memory than you were before (40GB).  Are you sure that you need to limit the number of threads to 2? If you have 72 available, it would be a shame to not use them.  I would start by lowering incrementally to see where the issue is rather than trying 2.

Comment: When I limit the max memory to 200 GB without nthreads, exception is same. I solve it when number of threads param is limited. Herein, 2 threads is just a trial. It returns exception when nthreads is greater than 36 (half of my total cores).